# inheritence in jaxb-generated classes

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I am using jaxb to autogenerate classes for unmarshalling xml content into a java application.  I notice that the resulting classes have a lot of redundancy.  In particular, the model into which they will ultimately be transferred uses inheritance to avoid the redundancy.  I am tempted to re-write all the generated classes so that they also use inheritance.  Is there a reason not to do this?

For example:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "A", propOrder = {"p1","p2","p3"})
Class A {
    @XmlElement(required = true)
    property p1;
    @XmlElement(required = true)
    property p2;
    @XmlElement(required = true)
    property p3;
}

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "B", propOrder = {"p1","p2","p4"})
class B {
    @XmlElement(required = true)
    property p1;
    @XmlElement(required = true)
    property p2;
    @XmlElement(required = true)
    property p4;
}
```

would become:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "Root", propOrder = {"p1","p2"})
@XmlSeeAlso({A.class, B.class})
Class Root {
    @XmlElement(required = true)
    property p1;
    @XmlElement(required = true)
    property p2;
}

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "A", propOrder = {"p3"})
Class A extends Root{
    @XmlElement(required = true)
    property p3;
}

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "B", propOrder = {"p4"})
Class B extends Root{
    @XmlElement(required = true)
    property p4;
}
```

If I make this kind of transformation, will the @Xml... annotations stop working?  Will jaxb still be able to unmarshal correctly?  If I do not simplify the code as shown above, I think the alternative is to build another set of middle classes to translate the unmarshalled data into my app's model.  Anyone care to comment or improve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Short Answer

JAXB will keep working if you make this change.

### Impact of What You Did

The way you have things if you regenerated the XML Schema from the Java classes you would see inheritance among the complex types.  You may want to make the `Root` class abstract so that no one can accidentally instantiate it.

### What More You Could Do

You could mark the `Root` class as `@XmlTransient`.  This would remove it from the type hierarchy and all of its properties would be treated as belonging to the subclasses:

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/06/ignoring-inheritance-with-xmltransient.html